# Is alkene reaction with hydrogen to form an alkane an addition reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, hydrocarbons

I have seen in some textbooks that such a reaction is listed under reduction of alkenes.

I understand that the double bond is getting reduced to single bond and one hydrogen atom is added to each of the carbons.

Should I classify this reaction as an *addition reaction* or a *reduction reaction*?

Comment: It is *both.* $%$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the *hydrogenation* reaction of alkenes is typically classified as an *addition* reaction. See [here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Hydrocarbons/Alkenes/Catalytic_Hydrogenation) and [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkene#Hydrogenation), for example.

Comment: OK the double bond gets reduced through addition mechanism. Its the underlying mechanism that dictates the classification. I am new here (<15 rep) can't up vote you. But thanks. I understood the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is an addition reaction... No doubt! And as there are more hydrogen now after addition so according to classical definition alkene got reduced!

Comment: This doesn't really add much to what was already in the question and what was already in the other answer.  Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Addition reaction means simply addition of any species without substituting whatever was there in the molecule before addition...the addition reaction here is across a double bond... the nature of the bond is changed after adding H2 but there was no substitution of any species...